# Android HttpUrlConnection simple Website connection

Tags: android

I want to check if a local website from my apache-server is up and reachable.
If read through countless threads about HttpUrlconnection and came up with the following code. Manifest Internet Persmission is set. The website is currently running and I can access it via my smartphones webbrowser. I´ve also read about Input and Outputstreams, do I need them for my task?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        state(value);
    }

    public boolean state(boolean value){
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.178.59:8090/");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
            value = true;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return value;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            value = false;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return value;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            value = false;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Solution from Exception

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new HttpTask().execute(value);

    }

    private class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean>
    {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean value=params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.178.59:8090/");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)     url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                value = true;
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return value;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                value = false;
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return value;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                value = false;
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return value;
            }

    }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean  result) {
             if(result){
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             }
             else{
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }

    }

}
```

EDIT: Service Solution

```
    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean  result) {
                if(result){
                    Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Notification in Status Bar
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotifiyService.this);
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dummy);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(NotifiyService.this, Main22Activity.class);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotifiyService.this,0,intent,0);
                    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dummy));
                    builder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.newNotify));
                    builder.setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.newNotify2));
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: What is the "task" you are trying to achieve?

Comment: And always perform any network call inside an async task.

Comment: This local website is intentionally down. At some condition it comes back online. In my main app (this is just a test for urlconnect) I want to have a service that regularly checks if the website is up or down. If it comes back online I want to display a Notification in the statusbar. I´ve already made a service in my mainapp, but I want to do the rest step-by-step, since I´m new to Android :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with below given code.

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new HttpTask().execute(value);

    }

    private class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean>
    {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean value=params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.178.59:8090/");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)     url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                value = true;
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return value;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                value = false;
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return value;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                value = false;
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return value;
            }

    }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean  result) {
             if(result){
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             }
             else{
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

To launch new activity on notification click, add these lines after `Intent intent = new Intent(NotifiyService.this, Main22Activity.class);`:

```
intent .setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Thx so much, thats what I wanted :-) so if I want that code to repeat in the background I have to paste that in my service, right?  
Posted the service in my main question.

Comment: Yes, most of it will remain same

Comment: Thx, I will try that

Comment: Hey, can take a look at my edited code in the first post? The notification works but when I click on it nothing happens (the Intent should open MainActivity22).

Comment: Thanks man. At first it didn´t work. I had to add the line builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent); and then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Simply run this code:-

```
  public boolean state(boolean value){
            URL url;
            String response = "";
            try {
                url = new URL("http://192.168.178.59:8090/");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);


                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                //writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
                writer.write(value);

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += line;
                        System.out.println(response);
                    }
                } else {
                    response = "";

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```